# List vs. && in Assumptions

Tags: assumptions

When one gives values to the $Assumptions variable, it seems to not matter whether you separate the conditions with `&&` or just give is a list of the conditions (see below). Is there any subtle difference I am not catching?

```
Remove["Global`*"] 
$Assumptions = {a>0 && b <=0}
Sqrt[a^2]+ Sqrt[b ^2] // FullSimplify
```

yeilds the same result as

```
Remove["Global`*"] 
$Assumptions = {a>0 , b <=0}
Sqrt[a^2]+ Sqrt[b ^2] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Your question isn't strictly about `Assuming`, you may want to use it instead. From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html): `Assuming converts lists of assumptions {a1, a2, ...} to a1 && a2 &&...`